# Trying to understand types in haskell library fused-effects

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I am trying to understand hmap.

```
module Main where

import Control.Effect.Fresh
import Control.Effect.Carrier

a :: Fresh Maybe Int
a = Fresh (\n -> Just 5)

b :: Fresh Maybe [Int]
b = fmap (\n -> [7::Int]) a

f :: Maybe Int -> [] Int
f mi = [1]

c :: Fresh Maybe Int -> Fresh [] Int
c = hmap f


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Just testing types"
```

**ghc error:**

```
• Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘Int’
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall x. Maybe x -> [x]
        at src/Main.hs:16:5-10
      Expected type: Maybe x -> [x]
        Actual type: Maybe Int -> [Int]
    • In the first argument of ‘hmap’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: hmap f
      In an equation for ‘c’: c = hmap f
   |
16 | c = hmap f
   |          ^
```

Why is there no match of x with Int?
The type signature of hmap is:

```
hmap :: Functor m => (forall x . m x -> n x) -> (h m a -> h n a)
```

My f function is declared in my code as:

```
f :: Maybe Int -> [] Int
f mi = [1]
```

Why is there no match between **`m x -> n x`** and **`Maybe Int -> [] Int`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the signature of `hmap`, it expects a function of type `forall x. m x -> n x`. The `forall x` in there means that it needs to work *for all possible `x`*, but your function only works for `Int`. It has the type `m Int -> n Int` (where `m=Maybe` and `n=[]`), but `hmap` requires `m x -> n x` for all possible `x`.

In order to use `f` with `hmap`, you need to define it in a generic way, such that it works for any argument type, for example

```
f :: forall x. Maybe x -> [] x
f (Just x) = [x]
f Nothing = []
```

(NOTE: `forall x.` is not necessary in this signature, but I included it to illustrate how `f` needs to match the first argument of `hmap`)

Answer (score 3):

`hmap` has NOT this type

```
hmap :: Functor m => (m x -> n x) -> (h m a -> h n a)
```

but has this type instead:

```
hmap :: Functor m => (forall x . m x -> n x) -> (h m a -> h n a)
```

The difference is that, in the first (fake) type, you can choose the value of `x`. In the latter type, instead `x` is chosen by `hmap` (and not by you).

In your code, you pass `f` to `hmap`, which amounts to choosing `x = Int`, but you are not allowed to do that. You need to define an `f` which is able to work with any `x`, e.g.

```
f :: Maybe x -> [] x
f mi = []
```